Making a small program to move from room to room in a text game. Cant update room or remove brackets from directions
So this is the code I have written for my school project. I simply need to be able to get user input and let them move from room to room.
rooms = {
    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}


def move_room(user_input, current_room):

    valid_directions = rooms[current_room].keys()
    if user_input in valid_directions:
        next_room = rooms[current_room][user_input]
        print("You have moved to", next_room)
        return next_room
    else:
        print("There is no exit that way.")
        return current_room

def main():
    while True:
        current_room = 'Great Hall'
        print('You are in the', current_room)
        print('You can move', rooms[current_room].keys())
        user_input = input("Enter a direction:")
        if user_input != 'exit':
            next_room = move_room(user_input, current_room)
            current_room = next_room

        else:
            print("Goodbye")
            break



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

This is what I get when I run the code.
You are in the Great Hall
You can move dict_keys(['South'])
Enter a direction:
You have moved to Bedroom
You are in the Great Hall
You can move dict_keys(['South'])
Enter a direction:
I dont remember all my exact steps. I had to step away for a few days cause I was stressed. I tried a couple differnt ways to get the dict_keys and brackets around south to go away but couldnt figure out how.
I also dont know how to get it to update the new room and not default to the great hall. I tried moving it to above the main function and accessing it as a global current_room.
Any help would be appreciated.
and incase anyone needs to know I am required to use a main function for the project.

One way to get rid of the brackets is to join the list items into a string, take a look at str.join().

Move current_room = 'Great Hall' above while True:

You can use join() method of strings to print just the dictionary keys formatted how you like:
print('You can move', ", ".join(rooms[current_room].keys())

Also, your code is moving the player back to the Great Hall at the beginning of each loop.
while True:
    current_room = 'Great Hall'
    print('You are in the', current_room)
    # etc.

Don't do that. Initialize the current room once, then enter your loop.
current_room = 'Great Hall'
while True:
    print('You are in the', current_room)
    # etc.


Thank you so much. I had been putting it below the while statement or above the main function but didnt even think to put them in between.
